# Vim highlighting: only overwrite background, not foreground color

Tags: highlight

I have highlighted keywords and characters in bold and in different fg colours (with `syn match`). When I create an area highlight (e.g. between [ ] or ( )) the character and keyword highlighting is being overwritten. How can I preserve the foreground colour and other styling while only changing the background colour?

I want to achieve a similar result as in Visual Mode, that preserves most of the highlighting, but only changes the background. Also SpellCheck and Search highlighting works that way.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! What do you mean by an "area highlight"? Do you mean a `syn region` command? If that's the case, then the problem is possibly that Vim is only matching that region and not other keywords (or syn rules) inside it... You might need an explicit `contains=` to let it know it should match other rules inside the region. Can you give more details on which rules you're adding and example text you'd like to match? Please [edit] the question to add more details.

Comment: Please use [edit]s for edits to the question (and it's easier if you do so from the same user account). Answers & solutions belong in answers.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem in understanding that the Search or SpellCheck functions are realized not via `syn match` or `syn area`, but by using the `match` function.

In my `.vimrc`, I now have:

```
highlight Dot term=standout cterm=bold ctermfg=Green
syn match Dot "\."

hi withinBrackets ctermbg=255 cterm=NONE ctermfg=NONE 
match withinBrackets /\[\_.\{-}\]/
```

If I have a string like "[whatever.]", the dot stays bold and green (like assigned from the `syn match` command), and additionally gets a greyish background (from the `match` command).

Comment: Maybe could you accept your answer using the v green button next to the arrow voting buttons. It will allow you question to rest :-)